# How can I run background script dynamically in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to run background script dynamically only when it needs to.

My background script creates a context menu based on an array which is stored in **localStroage**. Background script only runs once on loading, and I want to run the script again when user update an array in **localStroage**, how can I do that?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by that, at all, because "when it needs" is something that only makes sense to you. Edit your question to give a longer explanation.

Comment: That's better, but not exactly enough. How (where) can a user update the array?

Comment: @xan An array basically contains object and user create a new object and save it by clicking the button on UI page . then in popup.js  I update that array and now I want to run background script again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) were created specifically to address "background pages that do nothing most of the time" problem. They are unloaded after a few seconds of inactivity, and run again when any of the events for which handlers are registered occur.

Read the documentation - there are nuances as to how they must be structured. Also, specifically for context menus you can't use `onclick` parameter and must use the `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` event instead.

You can use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to wake up your event page from other extension contexts. Also, consider using [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) instead of `localStorage`, which comes with a `chrome.storage.onChanged` event.